# How to implement login via facebook google and twitter?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I want to login via `facebook`, `google` and `twitter` in `Yii` framework.

I don't know how to do it ?

Please suggest me the best way.

Comment: Have you made any effort to do it? Google gives plenty of results for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the developer site for each [facebook](http://developer.facebook.com), [twitter](http://developer.twitter.com) and [google](http://console.developers.google.com/). and simple create some app to work with as you needed.